# Trim Leading and trailing Spaces in Awk

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I have a file which contains 1 line like below

```
 VINOTH                                                                                    |KARTHICK                                                                                       |RAVI
```

I'm using the below command to remove the leading and trailing spaces , but it's not not working.

```
awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' Input_File
```

Please help.

Required Output.

```
VINOTH|KARTHICK|RAVI
```

Comment: Try `sed 's/[ \t]*|[ \t]*/|/g;s/^[ \t]*\|[ \t]*$//g' Input_File`

Comment: It's working. Could you please explain the Statement?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but you have one word in your input file, and it appears as 3 words with a pipe as the delimiter. ... how come?

Comment: Please use the horizontal scroll bar to see the full Line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may  use

```
sed 's/[ \t]*|[ \t]*/|/g;s/^[ \t]*\|[ \t]*$//g' Input_File
```

There are two regexps here:

- `s/[ \t]*|[ \t]*/|/g` replaces all `|` enclosed with optional whitespaces with a single `|` (the `|` in the regex matches a literal `|` char as per BRE POSIX standard)
- `s/^[ \t]*\|[ \t]*$//g` removes all whitespaces at the start and end of lines. Note that `\|` here is an OR operator (escaped because the BRE POSIX syntax is used).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/utNXlb).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(since your sample input and expected output are not clear so didn't test it).

```
awk '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```